# Help, please! Решаю задачку на codewars. Номера по порядку

Tags: javascript, null

Дан массив чисел в нем надо найти число идущее не попорядку и вернуть его. Если все числа попорядку нужно вернуть null.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему вместо null возвращается udefined и как это исправить. Спасибо)

```
function firstNonConsecutive(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let consecNum = arr[i] + 1
        let nextNum = arr[i + 1]
        if (consecNum != nextNum) {
            return nextNum
        }
    }
    return null
}

firstNonConsecutive([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]) //6)
firstNonConsecutive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]) //9
firstNonConsecutive([1, 2, 3, 4]) //null
```

Comment: Потому что nextNum  у тебя undefined на последней итерации цикла

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял.